# Turn to recursive method in common-lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

This is the coordinates for 3 boards of tic tac toe connected between themselves and i would like to know how can i reduce this code making it in recursive way.
All of this code below is only one method (vitoria):

```
(defun vitoria (tabuleiro)
    (or (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 1 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 1 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 2 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 2 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 3 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 3 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 3 3 tabuleiro))
```

columns between levels in position 1 - 3

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 2 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 1 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 1 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 2 2 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 2 3 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 3 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 3 3 tabuleiro))
```

columns between levels in position 2 - 6

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 3 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 1 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 1 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 3 2 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 2 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 3 3 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 3 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 3 3 tabuleiro))
```

columns between levels in position 3 - 9

```
       (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 3 3 tabuleiro))
       (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 3 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 1 3 tabuleiro))
```

lines between levels on top - 11

```
       (verificacaoXO (get-elem 2 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 3 3 tabuleiro))
       (verificacaoXO (get-elem 2 3 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 1 3 tabuleiro))
```

lines between levels in the middle - 13

```
       (verificacaoXO (get-elem 3 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 3 3 tabuleiro))
       (verificacaoXO (get-elem 3 3 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 1 3 tabuleiro))
```

lines between levels on bottom - 15

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 3 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 1 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 3 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 3 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 3 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 3 3 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 1 3 tabuleiro))
```

diagonal between levels - 19

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 2 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 3 1 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 2 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 3 1 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 3 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 2 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 3 1 tabuleiro))
```

lines on level 1 - 22

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 1 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 3 2 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 2 1 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 3 2 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 3 1 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 3 2 tabuleiro))
```

lines on level 2 - 25

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 1 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 2 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 3 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 2 1 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 3 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 3 1 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 2 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 3 3 tabuleiro))
```

lines on level 3 - 28

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 1 1 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 2 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 2 1 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 3 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 3 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 3 1 tabuleiro))
```

columns on level 1 - 31

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 3 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 1 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 1 2 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 2 2 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 3 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 3 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 3 2 tabuleiro))
```

columns on level 2 - 34

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 3 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 1 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 1 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 2 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 2 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 3 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 3 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 3 3 tabuleiro))
```

columns on level 3 - 37

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 3 1 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 3 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 1 1 tabuleiro))
```

diagonals of level 1 - 39

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 1 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 3 2 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 3 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 1 2 tabuleiro))
```

diagonals of level 2 - 41

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 1 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 3 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 3 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 3 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 1 3 tabuleiro))
```

diagonals of level 3 - 43

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 3 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 3 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 3 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 3 3 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 3 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 3 3 tabuleiro))
```

columns between levels on the right  - 45

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 2 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 2 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 3 2 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 2 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 2 3 tabuleiro))
```

columns between levels on the middle  - 47

```
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 1 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 1 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 3 1 3 tabuleiro))
        (verificacaoXO (get-elem 3 1 1 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 2 1 2 tabuleiro)
                         (get-elem 1 1 3 tabuleiro))))
```

columns between levels on the middle  - 49

Comment: Why use recursion? Why not use loops, e.g. [`dotimes`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_dotime.htm) or [`loop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm).

Comment: Is this a 3d tic tac toe? What is `verificacaoXO` doing?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution, in which the coordinates are generated. Each `point` consists of three integer coordinates that identify a row, a column and a plane. A `triple` is a set of three points that determines a line. The triples are generate starting from a point and adding a direction twice (a vector like `(0 1 0)`). The triples that are not valid are eliminated.

```
(defun valid-coordinate(c) 
  (<= 1 c 3))
(defun valid(triple)
  (loop for point in triple always (every #'valid-coordinate point)))
(defun add(point direction)
  (mapcar #'+ point direction))
(defun make-triple(point direction)
  (let ((pv (add point direction)))
    (list point pv (add pv direction))))
(defun make-triples(point directions)
  (loop for d in directions
     as triple = (make-triple point d)
     when (valid triple)
     collect triple))
(defun make-all-triples ()
  (let ((directions-on-plane '((0 1 0)(1 0 0)(1 1 0)(-1 -1 0)))
        (3d-directions '((0 0 1)(0 1 1)(1 0 1)(1 1 1)(-1 0 1)(0 -1 1)(-1 -1 1)(1 -1 1)(-1 1 1))))
    (nconc (loop for plane from 1 to 3
              nconc (loop for r from 1 to 3
                       nconc (loop for c from 1 to 3 
                                nconc (make-triples (list r c plane) directions-on-plane))))
           (loop for r from 1 to 3
              nconc (loop for c from 1 to 3
                       as plane = 1
                       nconc (make-triples (list r c plane) 3d-directions))))))

(defun vitoria (tabuleiro)
  (loop for triple in (make-all-triples)
     thereis (apply #'verificacaoXO (loop for (r c plane) in triple
                                       collect (get-elem r c plane tabuleiro)))))
```

Comment: Is verificacaoXO in the vitoria defun method supposed to be valid-coordinate?

Comment: `valid-coordinate` is simply a function that check if a coordinate is 1, 2 or 3. `verificacaoXO` is a function that you called to check (I suppose) if a triple is  a won for a player. My solution generates all the valid triples (i.e. triples with valid coordinates), then for each triple applies `verificacaoXO` to what is returned by  three calls of `get-elem` on the points of the triple.